Set interrupt pending in STM32H563ZI
I want to trigger SysTick (or any other) interrupt by setting the interrupt pending bit in some NVIC register to 1 (read it on the internet) but I can't find the register in the reference manual of my MCU.
I am using STM32H563ZI MCU.

Possible off-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925559/relationship-between-cpsid-instruction-and-generic-interrupt-controller-on-arm

The nvic is part of the Arm core. Refer to the Arm documentation for your Cortex M33 core. There may also be specific functions in the cmsis.h file.

Refer to Section 4.2 in the Programming Manual  for your STM32.
